# Modification of signed applications

Tags: macos, security, sandbox

I'm trying to get a better understanding of OSX Code Signing and the advantages that it affords me  in terms of protecting my software. Could someone please clarify certain questions for me?

Given an application that is Code Signed but **not** sandboxed:

Should a hacker change the application's binary the application is no longer considered as signed. However will it still run correctly (with the Caveat that Lion will warn the user about the application not being code signed)?

Given an application that is Code Signed **and** sandboxed:

What will not happen if a hacker changes the code in this case? Can he/she simply remove the entitlements file to create an unsigned version of the application that no longer has any sandbox restrictions?

Given a signed but **not** sandboxed application that contains a signed and sandboxed XPC service helper is there anything I can do to guarantee that a hacker can't create a non-signed (and modified) version of either part. It seems to me that as it currently stands a hacker can do the following:

- Create a binary-modified version of the helper. This new version
  would thus be non-sandboxed and non-signed.
- Create a binary-modified version of the main application. This new
  version would thus also be non-sandboxed and non-signed, and able to
  start up the new version of the helper.

Am I wrong? If so, why?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

You're basically right.  What you're looking for is copy protection, and that's something nobody's ever figured out how to do (well), and it's not something that either code signing or sandboxing attempt to do. What sandboxing does is limit the damage if your program is taken over *at runtime* and made to do things it's not supposed to. What code signing does is prevent someone else from passing *their* program off as *yours*.

I used the words "*their* program" intentionally. You have to realize that once "your program" is on someone else's computer and they start messing with it, it's not really yours anymore; it's theirs, and they can do pretty much anything they want with it. They can take parts out (sandboxing, etc) add parts (malicious code, etc), change things, ... They could even write a "completely new" program that just happens to include parts (or the entirety of) your program.

There are things you can do to make your code hard to modify/reuse, but nobody's ever figured out how to make it impossible. Apple isn't trying; their security measures are aimed at other targets.